# sheet.getProtections no longer works?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet-protection

I have a script that automatically protects a range of past Dates in my Sheet.

I use the standard `sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);`

It worked fine for several months but it has not worked since yesterday.

Is there any modifications on the implementations ?

Thank you

PS : 
the sheet object is well returned in my tests

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TRAVAUX");
var debug = sheet.getName();
var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
```

Error message when running the function

> Service error: Spreadsheets

[image]

Answer (score 7):

### There seem to be several developers with this problem, it might be a bug or a temporary problem.

The issue has been reported on [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/148894990). Give it a "star" to indicate that you are also affected.